# Trigger function in main form after serial data is received

Tags: c#, delegates, serial-port, nfc, invoke

I am making a program that reads values on NFC cards.
I have a class that reads values from Serial comms sent by an EMBED hooked up to an NFC IC. Once data has been received, the program (in the main form) must change 'page' and process the data.
I have used User Controls as different 'pages'.

I understand that there are multiple threads and i cannot change the GUI from a different thread without using some sort of Invoke/Deleagate?. However, i am unsure on how to implement this on my code.

Here is the code i have (with omissions of irrelevant code):

SerialData Class

```
public class SerialData
{
    public SerialPort ComPort;
    public String savedText;

    public SerialData()
    {
        ComPort = new SerialPort();

        // set port data
        ComPort.PortName = "COM5";
        ComPort.BaudRate = 9600;
        ComPort.DataBits = 8;
        ComPort.RtsEnable = true;
        ComPort.DtrEnable = true;
    }

    public void readCard()
    {
        try
        {
            savedText = "";
            ComPort.Open();
            ComPort.DataReceived += ComPort_DataReceived;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    private void ComPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;
        var data = serialPort.ReadExisting();
        savedText += data;
    }
}
```

Form1 Code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<UserControl> Pages = new List<UserControl>();
    public int CurrentPage = 0;

    SerialData SerialDataDriver = new SerialData();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Pages.Add(page1);
        Pages.Add(page2);
        Pages.Add(page3);

        // change to first page
        ChangeToPage(0);
    }

    private void Page1ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChangeToPage(1);
        SerialDataDriver.readCard();
    }

    void ComPort_DataReceived(string data)
    {
        SerialDataDriver.ComPort.Close(); /// close ComPort
        ChangeToPage(2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use `SerialPort` within the `Form` ?

Comment: You need to add additional methods to the SerialData to do the additional functions.  You probably want the readCard to return a string with the actual data.  A a new method to change pages.

Comment: Make your `SerialData` class raise a **Custom EVENT** that the main form subscribes to.  When that Event is received, you can then use a delegate/Invoke() to pass control to the main UI thread and safely change the "page".

Comment: @aybe - It needs to be in a class because the code is part of a bigger project.

Comment: @jdweng - I get a thread exeption when doing so. hence why i'm looking for help.

Comment: @Idle_Mind - Could you give me an example on how i could do that? Will it work? Thank you.

Comment: Also, you should only wire up the DataReceived() event **ONCE**, in the constructor of your class.  As it is, every time you call readCard() the handler will get wired up again resulting in multiple firings for each data receive event.  This will definitely cause problems for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a custom event:

```
public class SerialData
{

    public SerialPort ComPort;
    public String savedText;

    public delegate void Data(string message);
    public event Data NewData;

    private void ComPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;
        var data = serialPort.ReadExisting();
        savedText += data;
        if (NewData != null)
        {
            NewData(savedText);
        }
    }

}
```

...and how to wire up and receive it in the form:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Pages.Add(page1);
    Pages.Add(page2);
    Pages.Add(page3);

    // change to first page
    ChangeToPage(0);

    SerialDataDriver.NewData += SerialDataDriver_NewData;
}

private void SerialDataDriver_NewData(string message)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate() {
            SerialDataDriver_NewData(message);
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // do something with "message"
        this.label1.Text = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a wrapper that implements `SerialPort` events using custom `add` and `remove` accessors:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly SerialData _data;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Closing += (sender, args) => { _data.Dispose(); };

            _data = new SerialData(new SerialPort("COM5", 9600));
            _data.DataReceived += Serial_DataReceived;
        }

        private void Serial_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }

    public class SerialData : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly object _locker = new object();
        private readonly SerialPort _port;

        public SerialData(SerialPort port)
        {
            _port = port ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(port));
        }

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _port.Dispose();
        }

        #endregion

        public event SerialDataReceivedEventHandler DataReceived
        {
            add
            {
                lock (_locker)
                {
                    _port.DataReceived += value;
                }
            }
            remove

            {
                lock (_locker)
                {
                    _port.DataReceived -= value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```